# Execute method in JavascriptInterface after page has finished loading

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I would like to be able to do some processing on the html and javascript of a page before it is presented to the user of my app. The page uses window.open for all the links and that causes a new browser window, not controlled by my app, to be opened, which destroys to illusion of using an app. This is what I have right now, which I think will work for the most part.

```
class LinkFixer
{
    static HashMap<String,String>pages = new HashMap<String,String>();//static so multiple pages can access it

    public void processPage(String html)
    {
        html = html.replace("window.open","LinkFixer.openInNewTab");
    }

    public void openInNewTab(String url, String targetName)
    {
        if(!pages.containsKey(targetName))//targetName is unique for every link
        {
            pages.put(targetName,url);
            //add new tab to my TabHost, which will contain a WebView with page from url loaded
        }

        //move user to tab
    }
}
WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

browser.addJavascriptInterface(new LinkFixer(), "LinkFixer");
browser.loadUrl("http://serverIP:port/mobilecontrol.html");
//something to make the browser execute LinkFixer.processPage goes here
```

The problem I'll have with it, is that I'm not sure how I would make the page execute LinkFixer.processPage when the page finishes loading. Other than that, I think the code will work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up making a new WebChromeClient and overriding the onProgressChanged method to fix the links after newProgress is 100 or greater.

```
browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int newProgress)
        {
            super.onProgressChanged(webView,newProgress);
            if(newProgress >= 100)
            {
                System.out.println("Done loading");
                browser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].innerHTML = window.LinkFixer.processPage((document.getElementsByTagName(\"html\")[0].innerHTML))");
            }
        }
    });
```

Which works exactly how I want it to